Natural $\sigma$-algebra on $C[0,\infty[$: Prove equivalence of definitions
I am self-studying a textbook on probability theory, and I have arrived at a section on real-valued stochastic processes with continuous sample paths. Consider a process $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$. My book points out that such a process can be considered a map $\tilde X: \Omega\rightarrow C([0,\infty[)$, where $\tilde X(\omega)$ yields the function $f_\omega: [0,\infty[ \rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $f_\omega(t):=X_t(\omega)$. In order to determine whether this map is measurable, a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal C$ must first be defined on $C([0,\infty[)$. My book gives two possible definitions:

First define the map $\pi_t: C([0,\infty[)\rightarrow\mathbb R$ by $\pi_t(f):=f(t)$. Then set $\mathcal C := \sigma\{\pi_t: t\in [0,\infty[\}$
Set $\mathcal C$ equal to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra with respect to the topology of uniform convergence on compact intervals

The book then states without proof that these two definitions actually yield the same $\sigma$-algebra. Could someone please explain to me a proof of this fact? Any help would be much appreciated.

Note that under the given topology, the projections $\pi_{t}$ are continous and thus measurable in respect to the Borel measure.
As for the other direction, this topology is metrizable and separable, as such, any open set in this topology is the union of countable sets of the form $B_{I}^{\varepsilon}(g)=\{ f : |f-g|< \varepsilon \;\text{on $I$}\}$.
Now under $\mathcal{C}$, the sets $$\{ f: |f(t) - g(t)| < \varepsilon \}= \pi_{t}^{-1}( g(t)-\varepsilon, g(t)+\varepsilon)$$
Are measurable, and by continuity we have
$$ B_{I}^{\varepsilon}(g)=\bigcap_{t\in \mathbb{Q}\cap I} \{ f: |f(t) - g(t)| < \varepsilon \} $$
So $B_{I}^{\varepsilon}(g)$ is measurable, it follows that every Borel set is measurable.

In the second-to-last line, isn't the countable intersection equal to the closed epsilon-ball on I, rather than the open ball? The limit of a sequence of values strictly less than epsilon could still be equal to epsilon. Also, I can fill in this proof based on having seen these kinds of arguments before, but for completeness might be helpful to specify a bit more detail. For example, "This shows that the sigma-algebra defined by the projection maps contains all open sets, but the Borel sigma-algebra is by definition the smallest such sigma-algebra, hence this contains the Borel sigma-algebra.
